# vSphere PortMirror: What does "Source/Destination" mean as in "Remote Mirroring Source" and "Remote Mirroring Destination"?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, port-mirroring

The following is from vSphere's admin [doc](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-C3970893-9328-430C-A440-F22B7E26280A.html):

> To begin a port mirroring session, you must specify the type of port mirroring session.
>
> **Procedure**
>
> 1. Browse to a distributed switch in the vSphere Client navigator.
> 2. Click the *Configure* tab and expand *Settings*.
> 3. Select the *Port mirroring* option and click *New*.
> 4. Select the session type for the port mirroring session.
>
>    | Option | Description |
>    | --- | --- |
>    | Distributed Port Mirroring | Mirror packets from a number of distributed ports to other distributed ports on the same host. If the source and the destination are on different hosts, this session type does not function. |
>    | Remote Mirroring **Source** | Mirror packets from a number of distributed ports to specific uplink ports on the corresponding host. |
>    | Remote Mirroring **Destination** | Mirror packets from a number of VLANs to distributed ports. |
>    | Encapsulated Remote Mirroring (L3) Source | Mirror packets from a number of distributed ports to the IP addresses of a remote agent. The virtual machine’s traffic is mirrored to a remote physical destination through an IP tunnel. |
> 5. Click *Next*.

Every time I read this part I would be confused. I could never relate the word **"Source"** and **"Destination"** to what it says in the *Description* and so I could never remember who's who.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, you're asking what it means by source and destination when talking about port mirroring?

Comment: @Chopper3 not when generally talking about port mirror, but when saying the terminology "Remote Mirroring Source" and "Remote Mirroring Destination" as in vsphere's doc.

Comment: for example when we talk about "src ip" or "dest ip", src/dest just literally means src/dest. it's very straightforward and takes nothing to understand.